# Fock Space Representation of Particular Commutation Algebra

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, string-theory, conformal-field-theory

I'm looking at page 21 of the paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.4074) of Dabholkar, Murthy, and Zagier.  There they want to consider: "*The partition function of the chiral conformal field theory of 24 left-moving
transverse bosons of the heterotic string*"  They then pose the following commutation algebra,

$$[a_{in},a^{\dagger}_{jm}]=\delta_{i,j} \delta_{{n+m,0}} \quad \text{for} \quad i,j=1, \dots, 24\quad\text{and}\quad n,m=0, \dots, \infty$$

Now, I understand the $i,j$ parts: these are just the 24 directions in which you can put energy, so you essentially have 24 harmonic oscillators.  But I'm really confused by what the $n,m$ indices are referring to.  In particular, I don't see why $n=-m$ is special.  Can someone please explain to me what's going on here?

Finally, they give the Hamiltonian as

$$H=\sum_{i=1}^{24} n a^{\dagger}_{in} a_{in}-1$$

Why is there explicit dependence on $n$ here?  Should we also sum over $n$ to get the full Hamiltonian?  I'm also curious about what the energy eigenstates would look like given the above commutation relations, specifically how this $n,m$ index comes into play.

(Just for context, you should be able to evaluate the partition function $Z(\tau)=\text{Tr}_{\mathcal{H}}(q^{H})$ to get

$$Z(\tau)=\frac{1}{q} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigg(\frac{1}{1-q^{n}}\bigg)^{24}$$

Obviously the 24 makes sense.  And I know harmonic oscillators come with factors like $1/(1-q^{n})$, but the appearance of this infinite product is probably exactly due to what I'm confused about from the start :)  )

Comment: the $n,m$ indices seem to label the modes you get when quantising e.g. the bosonic string, $X^i\sim \sum_n \alpha^i_n$

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Thanks a lot, I need to read up on that.  Why don't those modes appear when you quantize the harmonic oscillator in any dimension?  I'm sure it's not correct, but I had sort of been thinking of the bosonic string as simply 24 harmonic oscillators